# Unable to install in nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nuget

I currently using VS2013, I'm using this for several months. I'm not encountering issue since then, but now I getting error. I unable to add package in my project.

> The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format. C:\project\NRMS\NRMS_Library\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\build\EntityFramework.props

I already add other package in this project last week, but now I'm encountering this issue. I do'nt want to mess up the current project because currently I have completed 50%. I already try create new project and try to install a package but getting same error.

Comment: which nuget packet did you try to add? some more info would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Vic, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click **Clear Package Cache** under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**General**

Or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache`

**Also**, delete `<solution_folder>\packages` folder.

**After that**, restart your project and then run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console.**

Answer (score -1):

This thread may add some light, check it out: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/482

In the 5th comment there's a guy recommending to get the code from an older version and provides the link.

Seems that an update changed the availability and caused the issue.